# Twitter API - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: twitter

I have a very simple snippet of code which was working till yesterday and has stopped working today?

```
var url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=dogs?callback=?';
var reddit = 'http://reddit.com/r/technology.json?callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});

//Error - GET http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=dogs?callback=jQuery172082220473815687_1365829251904&_=1365829251949 403 (Forbidden)
```

Here is the source - http://jsfiddle.net/ZeuKp/2

Can anyone tell why am I getting a 403 error. Have I exceed the rate on the API, which seems highly unlikely as I just switched on my local server?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not getting a 403 on that URL.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On January 14th, Twitter changed it so that only SSL/HTTPS connections are allowed when using their API.

403 errors are common signs that you haven't switched to SSL/HTTPS yet, in your app.

http://www.zdnet.com/twitter-enforces-ssl-encryption-for-apps-connecting-to-its-api-7000025138/

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by reducing the message characters length to 140. as defined here https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters.

Also you can check errrorCode and errorMessage by casting TwitterException into TwitterApiException.

```
 statusesService.update(newMessage, null, null, null,
                null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
                   @Override
                    public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
                        Debugger.i("success", result.toString());
                    }
                 @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        TwitterApiException twitterApiException = (TwitterApiException) e;
                       Debugger.e("failure", "getErrorCode() : " + twitterApiException.getErrorCode());
                        Debugger.e("failure", "getErrorMessage() : " + twitterApiException.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

One more point.
In case if you're using the API v1, for example like this library
https://github.com/twitter/hbc is used to access the stream API (https://stream.twitter.com).

Your project needs to have Elevated access and you need to apply for it because initially, it has only Essential access. The application is free.

You can check here if your project has the Elevated access
https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/elevated

Answer (score 0):

Very very very important: You need to apply for the "Elevated" access in your twitter dev account.

Answer (score 0):

Making the previous answer more understandable. For searching recent tweets, you will need to upgrade to basic plan, which is currently 100$/month

[image]

Also the pro plan has the permission for FULL-ARCHIVE SEARCH which the basic plan doesn't support