# Posting status update to Twitter returns 403 forbidden error

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm using the following code to try to post a simple status update to Twitter. Every time, I get a 403 forbidden error. I've tried it with multiple accounts and several different status messages. What am I missing?

```
ACAccount *account = [_accountsArray objectAtIndex:1];
ACAccountStore *account_store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *account_type_twitter = [account_store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
account.accountType = account_type_twitter;

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:requestURL parameters:dataDict];

request.account = account;

[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@", response);

}];
```

Comment: Hmm, finally tried it with another phone and it posted fine that time. No idea why it would work on there and not the first phone - I authorized the app to use Twitter and that was my first time trying to post something, so it's not like the API would've rate limited me.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was signed out of my Twitter accounts in the Settings app, I guess because I had switched to a new phone. All my accounts were still showing up when I queried the ACAccountStore, though, so I had no reason to think they weren't authenticated. I'll leave this up in case anyone else makes the same dumb mistake.

Comment: Voted up because I did make the same dumb mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same error and fix it by reduce the message characters length to 140.
try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35800216/5425082.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this error just now while trying to post an image to the test account. Resolved it by shrinking the image from about 4MB to 1MB.